# The simplest measures to run short code snippets securely on AWS Lambda

Tags: sandbox, aws-lambda

I would like to use AWS Lambda to run solutions to programming problems for an online courses website. So far, I use simple `eval` in my lambda function. However, many posts (e.g. [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/207725/294254) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/prhocr/can_arbitrary_code_be_safely_run_in_aws_lambda/)) suggest that a comprehensive solution is needed to make sure that malicious code does not render havoc.

Since implementing any sort of a solution seems to involve a very steep learning curve for me, I am wondering whether I can avoid problems by limiting a student's code to only 1 second of execution time.

If limiting the execution time to 1 second is not effective, what are the other simplest measures I can take?

Comment: Welcome to the community, but isn't this more of a programming question?

Comment: @SirMuffington I thought more in the direction of using an unprivileged account/role etc. I am actually wondering what damage if any can be done by a code when running under those restrictions. I hope to get by without any change to the lambda function itself.